# Как перемещать объект только по x?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект, на нём стоит скрипт(смотреть ниже). Этот скрипт передвигает объект при нажатии на него. Но хотелось бы сделать ограничение, чтобы перемещалось только по x. Как это можно сделать?

Скрипт:

```
    public bool MousePress;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        MousePress = true;
    }
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        MousePress = false;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 Cursor = Input.mousePosition;
        Cursor = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Cursor);
        if (MousePress)
        {
            this.transform.position = Cursor;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Вроде как должно помочь:

```
this.transform.position.x = Cursor;
```